# Extra area in my screen after installing linux mint or ubuntu

Tags: screen

whenever I install Linux Mint or Ubuntu operating system i have an extra area in my screen. (as shown in the picture below)

[image]

This extra area is not visible on my screen, but it is visible when I take a screen shot. It's good to mention my mouse can go in that area but I cant see mouse cursor when it goes there.
For example, right now that I am typing this question I only see the google chrome window but the extra area in right side is not visible.
How can I remove this extra area?

Comment: Please show us a screenshot taken from Ubuntu. Also mention your Ubuntu version and flavour.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you (or installer) have set up two video outputs.

- In **MATE** open *Preferences -> Hardware -> Displays* (or run `mate-display-properties`) and enable only one screen:

  [image: mate-display-properties]

  change *On* to *Off*
- In **Cinnamon** you can find similar settings in Cinnamon Control Center (something like `cinnamon-control-center` or directly `cinnamon-settings display`).
- In **GNOME** you can find similar settings in GNOME Control Center (something like `gnome-control-center` or directly `gnome-control-center display`).